# MySQL: DISTINCT in GROUP_CONCAT remove same values (not duplicates)

Tags: mysql, distinct, group-concat

I have two tables: *items* and *item_params*. *Items* table is usual list of items and *item_params* is table where there are several param names and its values.

```
+-----------------------------------------+
| id | item_id | param_name | param_value |
+-----------------------------------------+
|  1 |       1 | Width      | 80 cm       |
|  2 |       1 | Length     | 80 cm       |
|  3 |       1 | Height     | 110 cm      |
+-----------------------------------------+
```

I need one request so my query looks like:

```
SELECT i.*,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ip.param_name SEPARATOR '|') AS param_names,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ip.param_value SEPARATOR '|') AS param_values
FROM items i
LEFT JOIN item_params ip ON ip.item_id = i.item_id
WHERE i.item_id = 1
LIMIT 1
```

To avoid getting repeated value I use DISTINCT, but if *param_value* has the same values for different *param_name* it return only *80 cm|110 cm*.

How can I achieve to get unique *param_name* with all its *param_value* regardless same values?

Comment: It's `LEFT JOIN` ... `ON` ..., not `WHERE`

Comment: @axiac I know, my bad. This is just example...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expressions in the `SELECT` clause of a query are independent, each of them is computed using only the data involved in the expression.

What you probably need is to glue the param names with their corresponding param values then pass them to `GROUP_CONCAT` and `DISTINCT`.

Something like this:

```
SELECT i.*,
   GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(param_name, ':', param_value) SEPARATOR '|') AS params,
FROM items i
LEFT JOIN item_params ip ON ip.item_id = i.item_id
WHERE i.item_id = 1
GROUP BY i.item_id
```

This query should produce `Width:80 cm|Length: 80 cm|Height: 110 cm` and you can split this string and recover the param names and values in the client code.